# How pass locator as parameter

Tags: c#, selenium

I tried to create function which contain parameter with By type but i get error and i don't understand why

```cs
public void Set(By by, string cssselectorName)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.by(cssselectorName)).SendKeys("Hello");
}
```

```
  public void TestMethod1()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Functions f = new Functions(driver);
            f.OpenBrowser();       
            f.Set(By.ClassName,"email_create");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing it as following

```cs
public void Set(By locator, String textValue)
{
    driver.FindElement(locator).SendKeys(textValue);
}
```

**UPD**
I will bring some examples of passing `By` as parameter.
My code is in Java, but it is very close to C#.
I define `addBtn` `By` variable

```java
private final By addBtn = By.cssSelector("div.modal-content div.add-button");
```

I pass it to method

```java
public boolean clickAddButtonOnModalDialog() {
    return WebdriverUtils.clickVisible(driver, addBtn, 30);
}
```

The final method is:

```java
public static boolean clickVisible(WebDriver driver, By locator, int timeout) {
    try {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator)).click();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ConsoleLogger.error("Failed to click on element" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, i edited my question for more information

Comment: You trying to do that in a wrong way...

Comment: `By` object is something like `By addBtn = By.cssSelector("div.modal-content div.add-button");`

Comment: Do you know to tell me which way i need for pass locator as parameter?

Comment: Ha, i saw now you added solution, looks good, thanks a lot

Comment: Well, this is a small piece of automation code in some corporation with HQ in Tel Aviv :)